# How to hide kendo grid command edit button or delete button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to hide kendo grid command edit button  or delete button based on role.
+ How to hide command column if needed.Thanks

```
 { command: [{ name: "Details", click: showDetails },
             { name: "Edit", click: onEdit },
             { name: "Delete", click: obDelete, hidden:true}], title: 'Actions', width: 230 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case, if someone needs an answer (Reference: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.command.visible)

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { command: [{ name: "edit", visible: function(dataItem) { return 
dataItem.name==="Jane" } }] }
  ],
  editable: "popup",
  dataSource: [ { name: "Jane" }, { name: "Bill" } ]
});
</script>
```